# property is null when using xml serialization in webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send the below xml

```
<dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.uisol.com/model">
<extAlert SendFrom="SendFrom" Target="Target" OID="0" UrgentFlag="0" />
</dataset>
```

as a post to a webapi request

```
 HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SendNotificationRequest dataset)
```

with the classes defined as below

```
 [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.uisol.com/model",
     ElementName = "dataset",
     DataType = "string",
     IsNullable = true)]
    public class SendNotificationRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(
         ElementName = "extAlert",
         Namespace = "http://www.uisol.com/model")]
        public DRMSAlertRequest ExtAlert { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

public class DRMSAlertRequest : IDRMSAlert
{

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string SendFrom { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string Target { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string SendTo { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string BlindTo { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string ReplyTo { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string FailureTo { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public int OID { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string Subject { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string Message { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public char UrgentFlag { get; set; }
```

}

i have also made the xmlmedia formatter as below

```
 var formatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter {UseXmlSerializer = true};
            config.Formatters.Add(formatter);

            var xmlFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
            xmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
            xmlFormatter.SetSerializer<SendNotificationRequest>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(SendNotificationRequest)));
            xmlFormatter.SetSerializer<DRMSAlertRequest>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(DRMSAlertRequest)));
        }
```

I'm receiving the ExtAlert as null on the webapi controller. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
 httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

changed this to

httpRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";